# Hash key generation error on payumoney payment integration

Tags: javascript, php, payment-gateway, payumoney

I am trying to integrate Payumoney into my website. On the demo code provided by Payumoney hash value is created automatically when other data are filled. But In my code its not working (hash value not created).

My code is

```
    <?php

    if(strcasecmp($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'], 'POST') == 0){
    //Request hash
       $contentType = isset($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]) ? trim($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]) : '';    
       if(strcasecmp($contentType, 'application/json') == 0){
           $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
           $hash=hash('sha512', $data->key.'|'.$data->txnid.'|'.$data->amount.'|'.$data->pinfo.'|'.$data->fname.'|'.$data->email.'|||||'.$data->udf5.'||||||'.$data->salt);
           $json=array();
           $json['success'] = $hash;
           echo json_encode($json);

       }
        exit(0);
       }

    function getCallbackUrl()
    {
       $protocol = ((!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off') || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) ? "https://" : "http://";
       return $protocol . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . 'response.php';
       }

    ?>

   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" >

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"> 
   </script>


    <?php if (($rowcart['status']) == 1){ ?>

                                                           <?php 

       if(strcasecmp($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'], 'POST') == 0){
       //Request hash
       $contentType = isset($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]) ? trim($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]) : '';   
        if(strcasecmp($contentType, 'application/json') == 0){
           $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
            $hash=hash('sha512', $data->key.'|'.$data->txnid.'|'.$data->amount.'|'.$data->pinfo.'|'.$data->fname.'|'.$data->email.'|||||'.$data->udf5.'||||||'.$data->salt);
            $json=array();
            $json['success'] = $hash;
            echo json_encode($json);

        }
        exit(0);
    }

                                                            function getCallbackUrl()
    {
        $protocol = ((!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off') || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) ? "https://" : "http://";
        return $protocol . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . 'response.php';
     }

                                                        ?>
                                                        <form action="<?php ?>" id="payment_form" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" id="udf5" name="udf5" value="BOLT_KIT_PHP7" />
    <input type="hidden" id="surl" name="surl" value="<?php echo getCallbackUrl(); ?>" />


    <div class="dv">
    <span class="text"><label>Merchant Key:</label></span>
    <span><input type="text" id="key" name="key" placeholder="Merchant Key" value="" /></span>
    </div>

    <div class="dv">
    <span class="text"><label>Merchant Salt:</label></span>
    <span><input type="text" id="salt" name="salt" placeholder="Merchant Salt" value="" /></span>
    </div>

    <div class="dv">
    <span class="text"><label>Transaction/Order ID:</label></span>
    <span><input type="text" id="txnid" name="txnid" placeholder="Transaction ID" value="<?php echo  "Txn" . rand(10000,99999999)?>" /></span>
    </div>

    <div class="dv">
    <span class="text"><label>Amount:</label></span>
    <span><input type="text" id="amount" name="amount" placeholder="Amount" value="6.00" /></span>    
    </div>

    <div class="dv">
    <span class="text"><label>Product Info:</label></span>
    <span><input type="text" id="pinfo" name="pinfo" placeholder="Product Info" value="P01,P02" /></span>
    </div>

    <div class="dv">
    <span class="text"><label>First Name:</label></span>
    <span><input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" value="" /></span>
    </div>

    <div class="dv">
    <span class="text"><label>Email ID:</label></span>
    <span><input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email ID" value="" /></span>
    </div>

    <div class="dv">
    <span class="text"><label>Mobile/Cell Number:</label></span>
    <span><input type="text" id="mobile" name="mobile" placeholder="Mobile/Cell Number" value="" /></span>
    </div>

    <div class="dv">
    <span class="text"><label>Hash:</label></span>
    <span><input type="text" id="hash" name="hash" placeholder="Hash" value="" /></span>
    </div>

                                                            <button class="btn btn-xs"
                                                                    style=" background:#94c348; font-size:13px; width:100%;color:#FFFFFF" type="submit" value="Pay" onclick="launchBOLT(); return false;">
                                                                Make Payment
                                                            </button>
                                                        </form>
    <?php } ?>


    <script type="text/javascript"><!--
     $('#payment_form').bind('keyup blur', function(){
        debugger;
         $.ajax({
          url: 'profile.php',
          type: 'post',
          data: JSON.stringify({ 
            key: $('#key').val(),
            salt: $('#salt').val(),
            txnid: $('#txnid').val(),
            amount: $('#amount').val(),
            pinfo: $('#pinfo').val(),
            fname: $('#fname').val(),
            email: $('#email').val(),
            mobile: $('#mobile').val(),
            udf5: $('#udf5').val()
          }),
          contentType: "application/json",
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(json) {
            debugger;
            if (json['error']) {
             $('#alertinfo').html('<i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>'+json['error']);
            }
            else if (json['success']) { 
                $('#hash').val(json['success']);
            }
          }
        }); 
    });
//-->
</script>
   <script type="text/javascript"><!--
    function launchBOLT()
    {
         alert("hi");
        bolt.launch({
        key: $('#key').val(),
        txnid: $('#txnid').val(), 
        hash: $('#hash').val(),
        amount: $('#amount').val(),
        firstname: $('#fname').val(),
        email: $('#email').val(),
        phone: $('#mobile').val(),
        productinfo: $('#pinfo').val(),
        udf5: $('#udf5').val(),
        surl : $('#surl').val(),
        furl: $('#surl').val(),
        mode: 'dropout' 
       },{ responseHandler: function(BOLT){
        console.log( BOLT.response.txnStatus );     
       if(BOLT.response.txnStatus != 'CANCEL')
         {
            //Salt is passd here for demo purpose only. For practical use keep salt at server side only.
                 var fr = '<form action=\"'+$('#surl').val()+'\" method=\"post\">' +
        '<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"key\" value=\"'+BOLT.response.key+'\" />' +
        '<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"salt\" value=\"'+$('#salt').val()+'\" />' +
        '<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"txnid\" value=\"'+BOLT.response.txnid+'\" />' +
        '<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"amount\" value=\"'+BOLT.response.amount+'\" />' +
        '<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"productinfo\" value=\"'+BOLT.response.productinfo+'\" />' +
        '<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"firstname\" value=\"'+BOLT.response.firstname+'\" />' +
        '<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"email\" value=\"'+BOLT.response.email+'\" />' +
        '<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"udf5\" value=\"'+BOLT.response.udf5+'\" />' +
        '<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"mihpayid\" value=\"'+BOLT.response.mihpayid+'\" />' +
        '<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"status\" value=\"'+BOLT.response.status+'\" />' +
        '<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"hash\" value=\"'+BOLT.response.hash+'\" />' +
        '</form>';
            var form = jQuery(fr);
            jQuery('body').append(form);                                
            form.submit();
        }
     },
         catchException: function(BOLT){
             alert( BOLT.message );
         }
   });
    }

    </script>
```

On the code provided by payumoney, hash code is creted automatically when all of the form data are filled,
Is there any extra code required to create hash value from form data?

Any help?  Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you saying that `$hash` has no value? Are you getting to that code?

Comment: In the demo code, the hash code is create or change when changing form data, like changing name, email, amount etc. But in my code its empty. Or even it has a value, its not getting filling to the input field with id="hash", that is used for submitting the form

Comment: @LinuS, have you found the solution for this?